# how to prove translation invarient metric on vector space makes it topological vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Topological vector space has a property that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous operations.

I think it obvious that metric (translation invarient) on vector space makes it topological vector space But how to prove both operation continuous . I do not have an idea.

Please can anyone give me some hint or counterexample

Thanks a lot

Comment: Consider the discrete metric. How does that mesh with the topology on your scalars? Observe that the discrete metric is translation invariant.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Dear Sir Suppose our metric has translation invarient property then is that true?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir I got now

Comment: Glad to hear that! Feel free to flesh it out as an answer. To get more feedback :-)

Comment: For scalar multiplication, d(rx,ry) = |r|d(x,y) is needed.

Answer (score 3):

A translation invariant compatible metric implies that **if** addition is continuous at *some* point (typically $(0,0)$, of course) it is continuous everywhere. But it does not imply that it is continuous at some point, that is what being a TVS means. Also it means nothing for scalar multiplication: the discrete topology/metric on $X=\Bbb R$ makes addition continuous and the metric is translation invariant (always $1$, basically), but scalar multiplication as a map from $X \times (\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_e) \to X$ (where the scalars $\Bbb R$ carries the usual Euclidean topology !) is not continuous, as $(1, \frac1n) \to (1,0)$ while $\frac1n \cdot 1 = \frac1n \not\to 0= 1\cdot 0$ in $X$.

A Fréchet space is then assumed to be locally convex to make up for the scalar misbehaviour (we can use seminorms to build a better behaved compatible metric).

So we really need for Fréchet spaces that we have a TVS and a complete metric plus local convexity, e.g. We cannot replace TVS with a tarnslation invariant metric alone...

Comment: I'm confused. I thought (according to Jyrki Lahtonen's comments) a translation invariant metric does make vector addition continuous? For example, let's show continuity in one argument $f(x)=x+ y$ for a fixed $y$. Consider any $\epsilon$-ball $V$ with center $f(x_0)$, then $f^{-1}(V) = \{x: d(f(x), f(x_0)) < \epsilon \} = \{x: d(x, x_0) < \epsilon\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$, hence $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. What's wrong with this argument?